# Expecting TRIPLE_DOT, found ';'

Tags: java, processing

I'm writing a program using Processing but I keep getting **Expecting TRIPLE_DOT, found ';'**.
What could be wrong?

```
class Collision {
  Ball ball = new Ball();
  Block block = new Block();
  int ball_xpos;
  int ball_rad;
  int ball_ypos;

  int block_width;
  int block_height;
  int block_control;

    Collision(ball.xpos, ball.rad, ball.ypos, block.width, block.height, block.control){
    //
  }


  void detect_() {
    //not done yet
  }
}
```

Ball class:
    class Ball {
      int rad = 30;        // Width of the shape
      float xpos, ypos;    // Starting position of shape

```
  float xspeed = 2.8;  // Speed of the shape
  float yspeed = 2.2;  // Speed of the shape

  int xdirection = 1;  // Left or Right
  int ydirection = 1;  // Top to Bottom

 Ball() {
     ellipseMode(RADIUS);
    // Set the starting position of the shape
    xpos = width/2;
    ypos = height/2;
  }


  void display() {
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, 410, 40);
  }

  void move() {
    // Update the position of the shape
    xpos = xpos + ( xspeed * xdirection );
    ypos = ypos + ( yspeed * ydirection );

    // Test to see if the shape exceeds the boundaries of the screen
    // If it does, reverse its direction by multiplying by -1
    if (xpos > width-rad || xpos < rad) {
      xdirection *= -1;
    }
    if (ypos > height-rad || ypos < rad) {
      ydirection *= -1;
    }

    // Draw the shape
    ellipse(xpos, ypos, rad, rad);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the parameter names in your constructor, the dots (`.`) should be replaced with `_`. And you should give types to those parameters:

```
Collision(int ball_xpos, int ball_rad, ... so on){
    //
}
```

If you use `ball.xpos`, then compiler expects a *var-args* after the 1<sup>st</sup> dot(`.`) after `ball`.

---

But it seems like want to pass attributes of `Ball` class, to initialize the fields with the `Ball` class attribute. In that case, you should just pass a single parameter, that is a reference to `Ball`:

```
Collision(Ball ball) {
    this.ball = ball;
}
```

But I don't see why at all you are having those fields (`ball_xpos`, `ball_ypos`) in `Collision` class, given that you also have a `Ball` type field. You can remove them, and just set `ball` reference to the reference passed in the above constructor.

Same thing for `Block` type reference. You are simply having copy of the fields of `Block` and `Ball` in `Collision` class again. Not needed.

Comment: But I'm trying to call a variable `xpos` from the `Ball `class. Then make it equal to `x_pos`.